# ¿Como cambiar datos NaN en una columna, con una condición de otra columna?

Tags: python

al mirar los datos nulos de la columna 'Sexo', me percate de que los datos nulos se pueden rellenar acorde a la columna 'relación' ,ya que dice "Wife" y "Husband".

Ahora, ¿cómo puedo cambiar estos valores NaN de la columna 'Sexo' por  'female' o 'Male' segun corresponda (si en 'relación' el dato dice 'Wife',en la columna 'Sexo' Cambiar ese NaN por un 'Female' y si dice 'Husband' cambiar por 'Male')?

```
relación  raza   Sexo
Wife      White  NaN
Husband   White  NaN
Wife      Black  NaN
Husband   Black  Nan
```

Esas son las columnas python.

Comment: Esta pregunta no termina de quedar clara. Por favor, añade más información: ¿qué código has intentado? ¿Cuáles son los tipos de datos (NaN es indicativo de Not a Number, ¿estás intentado poner texto en unacolumna numérica?), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

```py
df.loc[:, "Sexo"] = df["relación"].apply(
    lambda x: "Female" if x == "Wife" else "Male"
)
```

Donde `df` es tu dataframe y se reemplaza la columna "Sexo" por completo (no sólo sus valores `NaN`).

En este caso, `apply` aplica una función tipo ***lambda*** (anónima) a cada uno de los elementos de la columna *relación* y devuelve una nueva serie de Pandas que se asigna a la columna previamente existente *Sexo*.

La función *lambda* tiene un parámetro de entrada `x` que corresponde al elemento actual de *relación* que se esté tratando y devuelve un string en función del valor de `x`. Nótese que las funciones *lambda* no tienen la palabra clave `return`.

Para no reemplazar la columna *Sexo* entera, sino sólo sus valores `NaN`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```py
import pandas as pd

df.loc[pd.isna(df["Sexo"]), "Sexo"] = df[pd.isna(df["Sexo"])]["relación"].apply(
    lambda x: "Female" if x == "Wife" else "Male"
)
```

Esta solución es similar a la anterior, pero filtramos las filas del dataframe con la función `pd.isna`.